# Casting to long long (GCC)

Tags: gcc, casting, long-long

```
long long x; double n;
x=long long(n);
```

This doesn't work. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any plain C / C++ compiler, in order to cast you have to use parentheses "(mytype)myvar", maybe you where confused because you required 2 separate words...

Answer (score 7):

The obvious:

```
x = (long long) n;
```

Answer (score 3):

C does not have constructors, this looks like a C++ constructor call.

In C, the syntax of a cast is a type name in parenthesis. It works as a prefix operator, changing the type of the expression to the right:

```
long long x = (long long) 3.14;
```